# Zend framework deployment in Bluemix

Tags: zend-framework, deployment, ibm-cloud

We would like to deploy Zend framework in Bluemix. We used the recommended buildpack https://github.com/zendtech/zend-server-php-buildpack-bluemix, however it does not help. For deployment we need to change Document Root to their 'public' folder.

In practice it can be done via changing apache configs or adding htaccess file. So we are not able changing the apache configs, therefore we added htaccess file for it. The folder has been created and via htaccess the document root has been changed (it works). But when the framework has been pushed it does not work (The blank page is appeared without PHP run-time errors).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [environment variable](https://github.com/zendtech/zend-server-php-buildpack-bluemix/blob/bluemix/environment.md) that configures the document root for an application using this buildpack:

**ZEND_DOCUMENT_ROOT**.

Using this instead of the htaccess rewrite rules should work.

Comment: Could you explain how to do it?  So how I understood there I should deploy Zend Server and application written in Zend Framework. But It seems to me that for this should be a global solution for all PHP Frameworks. Because we have already running  applications  in different frameworks and we would like to move them to bluemix.

Comment: Hi James, Could you please provide answer on Hayk's comment, because that is the problem on our side?

Comment: The standard PHP buildpack for Cloud Foundry [does not support](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/php-buildpack/blob/master/docs/usage.md) setting the document root via an environment variable. For a cross-framework solution, you will have to use .htaccess file with URL rewriting.

Comment: I found the solution. Please have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32700178/how-to-deploy-zend-framework-2-in-bluemix/32838510#32838510