# How to Deploy Zend Framework 2 in Bluemix

Tags: php, zend-framework2, ibm-cloud

I've deployed ZF2 application in bluemix system. After deployment I reach

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL / was not found on this server. error.

After I've added .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^APP_HOST$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.APP_HOST$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !public/
RewriteRule (.*) /public/$1 [L]
```

And getting error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message
>   'Unable to load ZF2. Run php composer.phar install or define a
>   ZF2_PATH environment variable.' in
>   /home/vcap/app/htdocs/init_autoloader.php:53 Stack trace: #0
>   /home/vcap/app/htdocs/public/index.php(15): require() #1 {main} thrown
>   in /home/vcap/app/htdocs/init_autoloader.php on line 53

I found [A CloudFoundry Build Pack for PHP.](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/php-buildpack#v3.2.2). I also tried how there described, but no result.

Comment: So have you run `php composer.phar install`?

Comment: There I haven't ssh access,  so I can't do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the way to deploy any PHP Framework to Bluemix system. I've tested ZF2 and Yii2 frameworks.
Add in

> manifest.yml

```
buildpack: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/php-buildpack#v3.2.2
  env:
    CF_STAGING_TIMEOUT: 15
    CF_STARTUP_TIMEOUT: 15
```

Create a **htdocs** folder.  Move all generated project files into this newly created **htdocs** folder with the exception of these four files:

1. **.gitignore**
2. **composer.json**
3. **composer.lock**
4. **manifest.yml**

Create a new folder in the root of our application named **.bp-config**.  Change directories into this folder and create a new filed named **options.json**.  Within this file, include the following json snippet:

> ```
> {
>      "PHP_VERSION": "{PHP_55_LATEST}",
>      "COMPOSER_VENDOR_DIR": "htdocs/vendor",
>      "WEBDIR": "htdocs/public",
>      "PHP_EXTENSIONS": [ "bz2", "zlib", "openssl", "fpm", "tokenizer", "curl", "mcrypt", "mbstring", "pdo", "FRAMEWORK NAME"]  
> }
> ```
>
> For Zend Framework 2  **"FRAMEWORK NAME"** to **"ZF2"**, for **Yii2** to **"Yii2"**.

Comment: I cant name a folder with "dot" as a first character.

Answer (score 0):

Please use zend framework buildpack instead:

https://github.com/zendtech/zend-server-php-buildpack-bluemix

```
# cf push -b https://github.com/zendtech/zend-server-php-buildpack-bluemix
```

Comment: Here is a good instruction for Laravel Framework: https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/2014/06/17/getting-started-laravel-bluemix/
Could you provide step-by -step example for other PHP Frameworks?